# Prolog: Why does it not use negative values in arithmetic?

Tags: date, math, time, prolog, difference

The code below is used to calculate the difference between two dates.

```
timediff(Id, Days, Months, Years) :-
    book_in(Id, date(Y1, M1, D1)),
    book_due(Id, date(Y2, M2, D2)),
    Days is D1-D2,
    Months is M1-M2,
    Years is Y1-Y2.
```

However, for my purposes I would like it to handle negative numbers, for instance, if a book was submitted early it would have a negative value to indicate it was returned before the due date, and a positive value to indicate it was overdue. 
Is there a different way to express this or have Prolog handle negative values?

Comment: But Prolog "handles" negative numbers: `?- X is 2 - 5.  X = -3.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, turns out my sample values in the code were the cause of my confusion: they would all give the 'incorrect' value